# Replace value into a datatable based on if condition of a shiny widget

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app:

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3"),
               uiOutput("book6")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","#tests",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })
  output$book3<-renderUI({

    selectInput("bk3", 
                "Label", 
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  })
  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to",
              value=NULL
    )
  })
  rt4<-reactive({
    if(is.null(input$bk6)){
        DF=data.frame(
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    else{
        DF=data.frame(
          Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        DF[DF==input$bk3]<-input$bk6
        DF
      }
  })
  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    rt4(),
    selection=list(mode="single") 

  )

}
```

As you can see I add a row every time by the `numericInput()` "tests". And then I use the `selectInput()` "Label" to choose one of the tests. When I choose a test then I rename it by the third `textInput()` "Change to".
The problem is that I want my `textInput()` to be empty by default as it is. So if this is empty then the "Label" in the datatable should take its name normaly by `Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2)` and not be empty as it is.
For example when the app is initially loaded the Label in 1st row should be "Test 1" and not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because your initialization is NULL however when the `input$bk6` is called it is not NULL but an empty character `""`. You can fix this by doing something like the following with your reactive dataframe.  Note the change to `is.null(input$bk6)|input$bk6==""`

```
rt4<-reactive({
     if(is.null(input$bk6)|input$bk6==""){
      DF=data.frame(
        Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    else{
      DF=data.frame(
        Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      DF[DF==input$bk3]<-input$bk6
      DF
    }
  })
```

However you might want to work on the initialization to fix this.  Something like the following might get rid of some of the warnings you get during startup.

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2"),
               uiOutput("book3"),
               uiOutput("book6")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","#tests",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })
  output$book3<-renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$text2)){
    selectInput("bk3", 
                "Label", 
                choices=(paste("Test",1:input$text2)))
  }})
  output$book6<-renderUI({
    textInput("bk6", "Change to",
              value=""
    )
  })

  rt4<-reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$bk6)){
     if(input$bk6==""){
      DF=data.frame(
        Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    else{
      DF=data.frame(
        Label=paste("Test",1:input$text2),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      DF[DF==input$bk3]<-input$bk6
      DF
    }
  }
  })
  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    rt4(),
    selection=list(mode="single") 

  )

}
```